# Get data from combined json arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have combined my 4 JSON results, and I would like to add them to a table, each json result has one field in common which is `cftools_id` but I have no clue how can I get those values into my table, at the moment after combining all 4 json I am not able to get any value.

Part of my code is the following:

```
$response = curl_exec($request);
$response_data[] = json_decode($response, TRUE);
$response1 = curl_exec($request1);
$response_data[] = json_decode($response1, TRUE);
$response2 = curl_exec($request2);
$response_data[] = json_decode($response2, TRUE);
$response3 = curl_exec($request3);
$response_data[] = json_decode($response3, TRUE);
print_r($response_data);
```

And the output that I'm getting is the following:

```
Array ( [access_token] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyIsW7QgE_xer8 [refresh_token] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.Y2M5NzMwZjE0NzU5ZjQ5MzIIV-LsuwTMmhEoqYyL0FxH7jn-U8ux8 [status] => 1 [0] => Array ( [duration] => 1.00ms [query] => Array ( [limit] => 10 [order] => Array ( [int] => -1 [string] => descending ) [service_id] => 5ebae5ec6b84e5d9da13c842 [stat] => kills ) [status] => 1 [users] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ebae56dd680afc0d72afa7e [deaths] => 1 [kills] => 1 [latest_name] => SuperM [rank] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5e602319b2e5f821e3c2c4f7 [deaths] => [kills] => 1 [latest_name] => DUDE [rank] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ec874cede95504740be5f11 [deaths] => [kills] => 1 [latest_name] => Badkubos1337 [rank] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ec877a1de95504740be6c53 [deaths] => [kills] => 1 [latest_name] => ogonedibairro [rank] => 4 ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [duration] => 3.11ms [query] => Array ( [limit] => 10 [order] => Array ( [int] => -1 [string] => descending ) [service_id] => 5ebae5ec6b84e5d9da13c842 [stat] => longest_kill_distance ) [status] => 1 [users] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ebae56dd680afc0d72afa7e [latest_name] => SuperM [longest_kill_distance] => 659 [rank] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5e602319b2e5f821e3c2c4f7 [latest_name] => DUDE [longest_kill_distance] => 15 [rank] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ec877a1de95504740be6c53 [latest_name] => ogonedibairro [longest_kill_distance] => 1 [rank] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ec874cede95504740be5f11 [latest_name] => Badkubos1337 [longest_kill_distance] => 1 [rank] => 4 ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [duration] => 1.06ms [query] => Array ( [limit] => 10 [order] => Array ( [int] => -1 [string] => descending ) [service_id] => 5ebae5ec6b84e5d9da13c842 [stat] => kdratio ) [status] => 1 [users] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ebae56dd680afc0d72afa7e [deaths] => 1 [kdratio] => 1 [kills] => 1 [latest_name] => SuperM [rank] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ebbfe62bac296098004820d [deaths] => 1 [kdratio] => [kills] => [latest_name] => Pizzanium [rank] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ec8765bde95504740be67c1 [deaths] => 2 [kdratio] => [kills] => [latest_name] => LaPanzer52 [rank] => 3 ) ) ) [3] => Array ( [duration] => 0.92ms [query] => Array ( [limit] => 10 [order] => Array ( [int] => -1 [string] => descending ) [service_id] => 5ebae5ec6b84e5d9da13c842 [stat] => playtime ) [status] => 1 [users] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ca912f5a1db3a13d4ea3181 [latest_name] => Rasta [playtime] => 301038 [rank] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5e602319b2e5f821e3c2c4f7 [latest_name] => DUDE [playtime] => 235173 [rank] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5e5efda04cac575569c1bdac [latest_name] => zENIngUeM [playtime] => 227736 [rank] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ebbfe62bac296098004820d [latest_name] => Pizzanium [playtime] => 166824 [rank] => 4 ) [4] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5eb41ad919f67c8dedf73065 [latest_name] => MatanssPT [playtime] => 115191 [rank] => 5 ) [5] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ebae56dd680afc0d72afa7e [latest_name] => SuperM [playtime] => 91596 [rank] => 6 ) [6] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5ead73af5046359aecddf716 [latest_name] => sentinella [playtime] => 79851 [rank] => 7 ) [7] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5eac5de8ccc616b8dd7cf625 [latest_name] => Kizaka [playtime] => 71706 [rank] => 8 ) [8] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5da2873aa835c936e94f94c0 [latest_name] => PT/BR - M0reira [playtime] => 63295 [rank] => 9 ) [9] => Array ( [cftools_id] => 5eb16a8285427ab9dae915ed [latest_name] => Tripmode_mtj [playtime] => 55356 [rank] => 10 ) ) ) )
```

The version easy to read in my opinion of the output:

```
    Array (
[access_token] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1OTA0MTA2NzgsIm5iZiI6MTU5MDQxMDY3OCwianRpIjoiMjYxNDdjYzEtZmFiMy00NGEwLTliYTItYjZmZjFmYTU5MWFlIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkwNDk3MDc4LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6IjVlY2FkY2M5NzMwZjE0NzU5ZjQ5MzIyNyIsImZyZXNoIjpmYWxzZSwidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInVzZXJfY2xhaW1zIjp7ImlwIjoiMTg4LjE2NS4xOTkuOSIsImludGVncml0eV90b2tlbiI6IjA4Y2QzNTU1MGZkMWZmYzk1MzViZGI3OGQzYTY3Mjc2Mzk4YzQzMDhjNWVmZTljMyJ9fQ.CBdETr6pvtajfZZU6nbYLNNM4t_gFPJIC1AUwxG9lfk
[refresh_token] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1OTA0MTA2NzgsIm5iZiI6MTU5MDQxMDY3OCwianRpIjoiNjE1MTMwZjEtN2VhMy00ODQ5LTlkMDQtZjUyNDk2MjliOGZmIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkxMDE1NDc4LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6IjVlY2FkY2M5NzMwZjE0NzU5ZjQ5MzIyNyIsInR5cGUiOiJyZWZyZXNoIn0.z8qIXrEhl47o18_pZdGDRmSSS0KsMKs0rgvNerYJ3Tc
[status] => 1
[0] => Array (
[duration] => 1.29ms
[query] => Array (
[limit] => 10
[order] => Array (
[int] => -1
[string] => descending
)
[service_id] => 5ebae5ec6b84e5d9da13c842
[stat] => kills
)
[status] => 1
[users] => Array (
[0] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ebae56dd680afc0d72afa7e
[deaths] => 1
[kills] => 1
[latest_name] => SuperM
[rank] => 1
)
[1] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5e602319b2e5f821e3c2c4f7
[deaths] =>
[kills] => 1
[latest_name] => DUDE
[rank] => 2
)
[2] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ec874cede95504740be5f11
[deaths] =>
[kills] => 1
[latest_name] => Badkubos1337
[rank] => 3
)
[3] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ec877a1de95504740be6c53
[deaths] =>
[kills] => 1
[latest_name] => ogonedibairro
[rank] => 4
)
)
)
[1] => Array (
[duration] => 1.52ms
[query] => Array (
[limit] => 10
[order] => Array (
[int] => -1
[string] => descending
)
[service_id] => 5ebae5ec6b84e5d9da13c842
[stat] => longest_kill_distance
)
[status] => 1
[users] => Array (
[0] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ebae56dd680afc0d72afa7e
[latest_name] => SuperM
[longest_kill_distance] => 659
[rank] => 1
)
[1] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5e602319b2e5f821e3c2c4f7
[latest_name] => DUDE
[longest_kill_distance] => 15
[rank] => 2
)
[2] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ec877a1de95504740be6c53
[latest_name] => ogonedibairro
[longest_kill_distance] => 1
[rank] => 3
)
[3] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ec874cede95504740be5f11
[latest_name] => Badkubos1337
[longest_kill_distance] => 1
[rank] => 4
)
)
)
[2] => Array (
[duration] => 1.15ms
[query] => Array (
[limit] => 10
[order] => Array (
[int] => -1
[string] => descending
)
[service_id] => 5ebae5ec6b84e5d9da13c842
[stat] => kdratio
)
[status] => 1
[users] => Array (
[0] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ebae56dd680afc0d72afa7e
[deaths] => 1
[kdratio] => 1
[kills] => 1
[latest_name] => SuperM
[rank] => 1
)
[1] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ebbfe62bac296098004820d
[deaths] => 1
[kdratio] =>
[kills] =>
[latest_name] => Pizzanium
[rank] => 2
)
[2] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ec8765bde95504740be67c1
[deaths] => 2
[kdratio] =>
[kills] =>
[latest_name] => LaPanzer52
[rank] => 3
)
)
)
[3] => Array (
[duration] => 13.06ms
[query] => Array (
[limit] => 10
[order] => Array (
[int] => -1
[string] => descending
)
[service_id] => 5ebae5ec6b84e5d9da13c842
[stat] => playtime
)
[status] => 1
[users] => Array (
[0] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ca912f5a1db3a13d4ea3181
[latest_name] => Rasta
[playtime] => 301038
[rank] => 1
)
[1] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5e602319b2e5f821e3c2c4f7
[latest_name] => DUDE
[playtime] => 235173
[rank] => 2
)
[2] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5e5efda04cac575569c1bdac
[latest_name] => zENIngUeM
[playtime] => 227736
[rank] => 3
)
[3] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ebbfe62bac296098004820d
[latest_name] => Pizzanium
[playtime] => 165999
[rank] => 4
)
[4] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5eb41ad919f67c8dedf73065
[latest_name] => MatanssPT
[playtime] => 115191
[rank] => 5
)
[5] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ebae56dd680afc0d72afa7e
[latest_name] => SuperM
[playtime] => 91596
[rank] => 6
)
[6] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5ead73af5046359aecddf716
[latest_name] => sentinella
[playtime] => 79851
[rank] => 7
)
[7] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5eac5de8ccc616b8dd7cf625
[latest_name] => Kizaka
[playtime] => 71706
[rank] => 8
)
[8] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5da2873aa835c936e94f94c0
[latest_name] => PT/BR - M0reira
[playtime] => 63295
[rank] => 9
)
[9] => Array (
[cftools_id] => 5eb16a8285427ab9dae915ed
[latest_name] => Tripmode_mtj
[playtime] => 55356
[rank] => 10
)
)
)
)
```

I just want to place the values of each `user` in one PHP table I have the following but it's not working:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>rank</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>kills</th>
            <th>deaths</th>
            <th>long kill</th>
            <th>kdratio</th>
            <th>playtime</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($response_data as $value): ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value['users']['rank']; ?></td> <!--From [0] => Array ( -->
        <td><?php echo $value['users']['latest_name']; ?></td> <!-- From [0] => Array ( -->
        <td><?php echo $value['users']['kills']; ?></td> <!-- From [0] => Array ( -->
        <td><?php echo $value['users']['deaths']; ?></td> <!-- From [0] => Array ( -->
        <td><?php echo $value['users']['longest_kill_distance']; ?></td> <!-- From [1] => Array ( -->
        <td><?php echo $value['users']['kdratio']; ?></td> <!-- From [2] => Array ( -->
        <td><?php echo $value['users']['playtime']; ?></td> <!-- From [3] => Array ( -->
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

All arrays have in common `cftools_id` and probably since some of them have users that others don't the one that has all the users is the `[3] => Array (` from where I need to get the `playtime`.

---------------- Update ----------------

This is the output of each array to one table:

SS: https://image.prntscr.com/image/Bg9kP6ztRkWXxo3QWVDdUQ.png

And I would like to have all that data in a single table, ordered by `latest_name` because some users don't appear in other arrays

Comment: users is an array as well, so you would need to use something like ['users'][0]['rank]. But it would be better to do an foreach on users directly.

Comment: With  ['users'][0]['rank] I can see some values in the table already but for example, user SuperM is repeated, and I don't want it repeated I'm also getting much warnings. SS of output: https://prnt.sc/snm2k6

Comment: I wasn't planning on doing your work, I was merely giving you a starting point. You need to familiarize yourself with arrays and how to loop over them with a foreach loop. There is a  ' missing after rank, that is probably causing the errors.